# AppKit prevent tracking area updates

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nsscrollview, nsevent, nstrackingarea

Some built in AppKit components temporarily "pause" `NSTrackingArea` updates while their content is being scrolled or resized. For example, if you inspect tracking areas using the Quartz Debug tool, you can see that tracking areas embedded in an `NSScrollView` don't move onscreen as the content is being scrolled, and only update when scrolling ends. Tracking areas within `NSSplitView` panes similarly don't update while the panes are being resized. How do these components achieve this behavior?

I'm working on a custom scrolling component that handles `scrollWheel` events and enters a mouse tracking loop as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html) and I'd like to replicate this behavior as a performance improvement.

Comment: I'd guess it's a side effect of running the main `RunLoop` in `RunLoop.Mode.eventTracking`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, my event tracking code is using the using `RunLoop.Mode.eventTracking` via the `NSWindow.nextEvent(matching:until:inMode:dequeue:)`, which doesn't achieve this, unless I'm missing some other step

Comment: `NSSplitView` sends itself `_startLiveResizeAsTopLevel` before its tracking loop, and `_endLiveResizeAsTopLevel` afterwards. My guess is that's how it disables tracking rect updates. Unfortunately there's no corresponding public API that I'm aware of.